# Importing PyTorch in PyCharm using Anaconda

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, artificial-intelligence, pytorch

I just installed PyCharm and Anaconda. I installed PyTorch to Anaconda and i can even use "import torch" in Anaconda. I've created a new Project in PyCharm with the Anaconda Interpreter but i still can't use PyTorch in PyCharm.

Comment: What do you mean by "_can't use_"? Are there error messages?

Comment: Well the error is "No module named torch"

Comment: go to file -> settings -> project -> project interpreter and make sure that it is using Anaconda Python and not the standard Python installation

Comment: Yea i already checked that, im using the Anaconda Interpreter, still not working

Answer (score 1):

[image: Running pycharm from within anaconda env window]

I had this problem also. Program that imported torch worked fine at anaconda prompt running in my pytorch env,  but when i ran pycharm from the windows shortcut and EVEN set my environment to use pytorch env, it would complain torch could not be imported. 
When i ran pycharm from the prompt as shown, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem and solved it:

1. After you installed anaconda, source activate your own envrionment.
2. Install pycharm-community and pytorch follow their official instructions.
3. Start pycharm-community in the same anaconda environment.
4. Loading your own project, followed instructions as Manuel Lagunas
5. Finally, you have to install **packages of torch** in the environment of pycharm:
    pictures as: 
   [press '+' on the right side to install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2j2Z.png)
   [you can choose packages of torch by typing 'torch'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sKSO.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you used a bash script and the conda environment to run python codes in your PyCharm IDE.
You also need `source activate myenv` in your bash script.

Like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

source activate myenv

python test.py

source deactivate
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and you that how i solved the problem:
1- when you open project choose conda as your project interpreter as shown here

[image]

2- in your project go to **setting** -> **project: project name** -> **Project Interpreter** check that you are using Conda Package Manager and your anaconda local settings

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved this in Windows 10 after sinking an entire morning into it.

1. Create a new Conda environment (via PyCharm or however you fancy)
2. Navigate to `C:\Your\Environment\Path\Scripts` in a command terminal

   - Mine looks like this: `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Snek_V2\Scripts`
3. Find what commands you would need for a `pip` install from the [PyTorch website](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/)

   - They'll look something like this:
   - `pip3 install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.0.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`
   - `pip3 install torchvision`
4. In the command terminal, you want to enter those commands with one difference; you'll need to replace `pip3` with `pip.exe`. As you've navigated to the exact environment you plan to work in, this will be the `pip` relevant to you.

   - e.g. `pip.exe install torchvision`
5. Open PyCharm and open the project that's working in the Conda environment we just set up.
6. If you open up a Python Console, you should now be able to enter `import torch` and **not** have any errors pop up in response.